# Displaying second dialog from button click in first dialog closes first dialog

Tags: android, dialog, onclicklistener

In my app, I'm using an `AlertDialog` with a custom view.  This view contains a couple of `EditText`s and a few other things.  There are some listeners attached to the `EditText`s that perform whatever functionality is needed.

On the button click of the dialog, I am performing some validation on the data entered into the `EditText`s and display another `AlertDialog` if the data is invalid.  Once that (second) dialog is closed, I want to remain on the main dialog (with the custom view), but for some reason that dialog is closed before my second dialog is shown.  How can I keep the original (custom view) dialog still open under the second dialog?

Here's my (simplified) code:

```
final EntryPanel panel = new EntryPanel(OrderActivity.this);

AlertDialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(OrderActivity.this)
    .setCancelable(true)
    .setView(panel)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            final int id = pePanel.getProductId();
            if(!isValidProduct(id)) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(OrderActivity.this)
                    .setMessage(R.string.error_unknown_product)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg2, int which) {
                            dlg2.cancel();

                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            }
            else {
                processProductEntry(id);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's not possible to keep both dialogs open.  Therefore I changed the first dialog (with the custom view) to be an activity with `theme` being `Theme.Dialog` - it displays the way it should - and then open the second dialog from it.  This way, when the second dialog is opened, the original activity (which looks like a dialog) is still visible in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I soled it like that:

```
public class PayDebtsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener
{
public interface OnDebtPayListener{
    void debtPayed(BalanceItem debt, double payedAmount);
    void badPayment(int errorCode);
}

private static final String LOG_TAG = "PayDebtsDialogFragment";
private static final int BAD_PARSING = -1;

private OnDebtPayListener onDebtPayListener;
private BalanceItem debtPayment;
private EditText etAmount;

public void setOnDebtPayListener(OnDebtPayListener onDebtPayListener) {
    this.onDebtPayListener = onDebtPayListener;
}

public BalanceItem getDebtPayment() {
    return debtPayment;
}

public void setDebtPayment(BalanceItem debtPayment) {
    this.debtPayment = debtPayment;
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setView(getDialogLayout())
           .setTitle("Pay debt")
           .setNegativeButton("cancel", this)
           .setPositiveButton("pay", this);

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
{
    if(which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE){
        if(onDebtPayListener != null){
            try {
                String strPayment = etAmount.getText().toString().trim();
                double payment = Double.valueOf(strPayment);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "debtPayed()");
                onDebtPayListener.debtPayed(debtPayment, payment);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "badPayment()", e);
                onDebtPayListener.badPayment(BAD_PARSING);
            }
        }else{
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onDebtPayListener is NULL");
        }
    }

    dismiss();
}

private View getDialogLayout()
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pay_debts_dialog_fragment, null);

    TextView tvPayer = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.tvPayDebts_payer);
    tvPayer.setText(debtPayment.getPayer().getName() + " pays");

    etAmount = (EditText) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.etPayDebts_Amount);
    String hint = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "Total debt: %.2f%s", debtPayment.getAmount(),
                                debtPayment.getCurrency());
    etAmount.setHint(hint);

    TextView tvReceiver = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.tvPayDebts_Receiver);
    tvReceiver.setText("to " + debtPayment.getReceiver().getName());

    return dialogLayout;
}

}
```

- I used a DialogFragment and defined my own listener with 2 mothods.
- I implement that interface inside my activity.
- When the input is bad, the activity shows error dialog (another dialog), and when it close I show the first dialog again.

Comment: Naturally, this would work and I considered it.  But this is a hack and with my specific logic would be rather painful to implement, since the two (inner and outer) dialogs manipulate data inside each other.  Additionally, I'm targeting API 7 (client's requirements) and thus prefer to avoid using fragments as that would require compatibility package. If there's no other way of doing it, I'd rather change the first dialog to be an activity with theme being dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I already faced the same problem and searched a lot but didn't find anything relevant to this.

So, I just used a little hack there to achieve almost my requirements.

First of I declare AlertDialogs :

```
AlertDialog.Builder subDialog,mainDialog;
```

Then use hack like this :

```
        subDialog =  new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity2.this)
        .setMessage("New Dialog Opened") 
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg2, int which) {
                dlg2.cancel();
                mainDialog.show();
            }
        });  


        mainDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity2.this)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setMessage("First Dialog Opened")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                subDialog.show();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        mainDialog.show();
```

What I did is on ok action of secondly opened subdialog, I again call show action for MainDialog.

Hope it will helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: Naturally, this would work and I considered it.  But this is a hack and with my specific logic would be rather painful to implement, since the two (inner and outer) dialogs manipulate data inside each other.  If there's no other way of doing it, I'd rather change the first dialog to be an activity with theme being dialog.