# Re-display parent dialog after child dialog closes

Tags: android, dialog, dialogfragment

In my app, I display a custom Dialog (using DialogFragment), which on certain action causes another custom Dialog to be shown (using another DialogFragment).  This all works fine.  However when the "child" dialog is closed, I want to return to the parent dialog (which is closed/hidden when the child is displayed).

I do not want just display another instance of the same dialog, as I need to maintain states and behaviours of the parent prior to the child being open.  Therefore I need to re-display physically the same dialog.

I can't seem to find a way of doing so.

Comment: ... don't close the "parent" before showing the "child"?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I don't close it - Android automatically closes it without giving any option not to.

Comment: Because I normally close a DialogFragment after using it, by explicitly calling the `dismiss()` method.

Comment: Yes, I do that as well when working with one fragment only.  However android automatically closes all other dialogs when displaying a new one (I believe full screen dialogs are an exception, but may be wrong).

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll leave the comments because I find this small discussion useful to other people as well.

Comment: Hehe :) Interestingly, I just found [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566593/displaying-second-dialog-from-button-click-in-first-dialog-closes-first-dialog) from three years ago, asking pretty much the same thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to it as I now got a solution that seems to work.  Apparently, using `dialog` directly will close the previous dialog when a new one is opened.  Yet, when using `DialogFragment`, the previous fragment stays on screen when the new fragment is displayed.  Then when the dialog on the new fragment is closed the previous fragment is still visible - exactly what I need.